# Finding the equation of the nine-point circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[Question (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5leI.jpg) 
[image]

I am struggling with finding the equation of the nine-point circle in (1). The "c" in the vertices are confusing me. I have found the midpoints of AB, AC, and BC in terms of "c", but in order to find the equation I need to get either three points on that circle or the coordinates of the center of the circle.

In terms of "c", I found the following midpoints:

$M_{BC} = (-2c+2,\frac{-c}{2})$

$M_{AB} = (-2c+2,0)$

$M_{AC} = (-4, \frac {-c}{2})$

I also found, what I think should be the center of the circle in terms of "c":

$U=(-c+3, \frac{-c}{4})$

I don't know if I am correct. Can someone please assist me with some guidance on how to get the equation for the nine-point circle?

Comment: The 3 midpoints of the sides of the given triangle are correct. Do you know that the 9-point circle of a triangle passes through the midpoints of its sides? You already have what is needed to determine the equation of the 9-point circle.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Welcome to MSE.

Hint:As you see in figure the triangle is rightangled at A.

1-A is where three altituds intersect. O is the center of circumcircle and it is on mid point of BC.The center of nine point circle N is the mid point of segment connecting A and O.

2- The measure of radius of nine point circle is half of the radius of circumcircle , so $r=NA=\frac{BC}4$

3- the equation of circle is:

$ (x-x_O)^2+(y-y_O)^2=r^2$

4- the figure shows that two circles are tangent because their centers are collinear and also they both cross vertex A.

I think these are enough data to answer all questions.